# Regex to match a fixed sub string in a String

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to verify the presence of a specific number in a fixed position in a String.

```
String: 109300300330066611111111100000000017000656052086116020170111Name 1
Number to find:  111111111 (Staring from position 17)
```

I have written the following regular expression:

```
^.{16}(?<Ones>111111111)(.*)
```

My understanding is:

1. Let first 16 characters be whatever they are
2. Use the `Named Capturing Group` to grab the specific word
3. Let the rest of the characters be whatever they are

I am new to regex, is there any issue with the above approach?
Can it be done in other/better way?

I am using Java 8.

Comment: The trailing `(.*)` looks superfluous. If you're in a programming environment, it would probably be easier to use `.slice` (JS) or the equivalent, to just plain extract the substring.

Comment: @CertainPerformance But a plain substring operation might give the wrong result and match the substring in a wrong position.  Also, the OP's particular API may require a pattern matching the entire string (e.g. Java's `String#matches`), so the `.*` at the end might be necessary.

Comment: Are there any requirements for the leading 16 characters? Like non blank?

Comment: I don't have a problem with your current pattern.  Do you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In JS, I was thinking of `'109300300330066611111111100000000017000656052086116020170111Name 1'.slice(16, 25) === '111111111'`

Comment: @dawg Yes, this is a record from a fixed length file.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I can't use substring/slice as this has to to be done through regex only.

Comment: If your code/regex _works_ and you're looking for optimizations, it's more appropriate to ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If the `111111111` is hard-coded into the regular expression, capturing it seems unnecessary - either the regex matches or it doesn't, and if it does match, then you already know what the `Ones` group would necessarily contain, without examining it.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thanks for the edit and the suggestion. I will keep it mind.

Comment: What language are you actually using?  This looks like .NET regex syntax to me, not Java.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using Java 8. Added in the question.

Comment: The answer to your question is already contained in the comments and answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more details of why you're doing what you're doing, there's just one possible improvement I can see. You repeated any character 16 times at the beginning of the string rather than writing out 16 `.`s, which is nice and readable, but then, it would be nice to do the same for the repeated `1`s:

```
^.{16}(?<Ones>1{9})(.*)
```

Otherwise, the string of `1`s is hard to understand without the coder manually counting how many there are in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hard-code the ones and you know the starting position and you just wnat to know if it is there, using a regex seems unnecessary. you can use this:

```
String s = "109300300330066611111111100000000017000656052086116020170111Name 1";
if (s.indexOf("111111111").equals(16) doSomething();
```

Another possible solution without regex:

```
if(s.substring(16,25).equals("111111111") doSomething();
```

Otherwise your regex looks good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The API I am using expect it needs to be a regex only as it works on pattern matching. I can't use sub string or other solution here.